# Grunt LiveReload is really slow

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs

This is probably an affect of my inefficient setup and not a problem with grunt/livereload.

Here's my watch test in my grunfile.js:

```
watch: {
    images: {
        files: ['images/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}', 'images/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
        tasks: ['imagemin'],
        options: {
            spawn: false
        }
    },
    js: {
        files: ['js/*.js','js/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['jshint'],
        options: {
            spawn: false
        }
    },
    svgs: {
        files: ['images/*.svg','images/**/*.svg'],
        task: ['svgmin'],
        options: {
            span: false
        }
    },
    scss: {
        files: ['sass/*.scss', 'sass/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass','autoprefixer'],
        sourceComments: 'normal',
        options: {
            nospawn: true,
            livereload: true
        }
    }
},
```

This will recompile my SASS and the reload the page, but it takes 5-6 seconds to complete the CSS compilation, then it does a full page refresh, instead of just reloading the CSS file that changed.

So my questions are this:

1. How do I keep it from taking so long to compile the SASS and refresh the page, or am I just being to picky, and this is an inherit part of grunt?
2. How keep if from reloading the entire page, and just reload the CSS file that changed from my SASS compilation?

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/time-grunt can show you which tasks are taking the most time and help you to optimize the tasks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check my other answer: [Fastest way to compile SCSS (Compass) + refresh the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934044/fastest-way-to-compile-scss-compass-refresh-the-browser/20935907#20935907)

[grunt-contrib-sass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) uses Ruby sass which is very slow, it has nothing to do with grunt itself.

Use [grunt-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass) instead, it uses libsass which is lighting fast c implementation of sass.

Read this article:
http://benfrain.com/lightning-fast-sass-compiling-with-libsass-node-sass-and-grunt-sass/

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to move from grunt-contrib-sass to grunt-sass, but if you don't have much time to fix this, i think, you should move your 'autoprefixer' task from watch section to deploy section.

```
scss: {
    files: ['sass/*.scss', 'sass/**/*.scss'],
    tasks: ['sass',
    sourceComments: 'normal',
    options: {
        nospawn: true,
        livereload: true
    }
}
```

In my project this trick help me, because 'autoprefixer' task works very slowly

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a live reloader tool, like [fast-live-reload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-live-reload), in combination with the ruby sass compiler.

Note that they offer their own watcher that *is very fast* (e.g. for compass run: `compass watch`).

*Disclaimer: I am the creator of fast-live-reload.*