# How to speedup Yeoman's grunt serve task?

Tags: performance, node.js, gruntjs, npm, yeoman

When testing realtime changes to my app using the `grunt serve` It takes between 6 to 10 seconds for the changes to show/update in the browser.

I used `grunt serve --verbose` to check for what task takes more time than other and found the folowing tasks consume most of the load time (*in descending order*);

1. `concurent:server`
2. `grunt-contrib-imagemin`
3. `grunt-karma`
4. `grunt-google-cdn`

Since I don't use cdn I removed it from `Gruntfile.js` but it still called; which is a bit confusing :( so I removed it also from the `package.json` and it disappeared.

So my questions are.

1. How to speed up the `grunt serve` to reload the browser instantly? but also preserve all "juice" of useful tasks (minify, uglify, imagemin..) when using `grunt build`.
2. Why when I disable a task on Gruntfile.js it still loads?

Thanks :)

Comment: Strange why no one answered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this post: [Grunt LiveReload is really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243315/grunt-livereload-is-really-slow) discusses the same problem and I believe it solves it. I'm yet to try it out and update this post if it helps.

Comment: I noticed a speed increase when i fresh installed windows 8.1.. strange but it is faster now.. Gonna check those links. Thanks